# JavaScript how to include hash in variable that detects current domain?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to detect an href click and do something if the link is an external link.  I have the following JavaScript in place to detect external links:

```
 var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);
```

I then use the following to do something if an external link is detected:

```
  else if (href != isThisDomain) {
               // do something for external links
          }
```

This works for external links but also fires for internal links with a #. For example, if my site is www.example.com I DO NOT want this to fire if href is www.example.com/#anchor or www.example.com/category/#anotheranchor.

How do I change isThisDomain to cater for this hash?

Comment: What is the value of `href` in the first part? What is the value of `href` in the second part? Are these the same variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using document.location.hostname (which only gets the host name part of the URL and excludes everything else) and comparing it to the URL you have?

Comment: Thanks, this seems rather obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this to every link on the page, you'll need to set an `EventListener` on all links that check the `host` property on them. If it's external, do whatever you need to. It looks like this:

```js
function checkHref(e) {
    var url = e.target.href,
      externalUrl = e.target.host !== document.location.hostname;

    if (externalUrl) {
      console.log(e); // Place your logic here.
    }  

    e.preventDefault();
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    i;

// Loop through all anchor elements and add an EventListener
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var el = links[i];

    el.addEventListener('click', checkHref, false);
}
```